# Requiring unknown module "crypto" in react-native environment

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm writing a simple Twitter app using react-native. Using [twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) module to get twitter feeds and stream. Below is the code, it works fine node. However, when included into my react-native app, seeing error "Requiring unknown module "crypto"". Dependency seems to be myapp->twit->oauth->crypto (thats part of node v0.12.2). Any suggestions to get this working inside react-native environment?

```
var Twit = require('twit')
var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:''
  , consumer_secret:''
  , access_token:''
  , access_token_secret:''
})
var filtered_tweets=[];
var error;
var isSuccess=false;

function getTweets(searchString){
    T.get('search/tweets',{q:searchString, count:100}, getResponse);
    }

function getResponse(err,data,response){
        if(err) { 
            handleGetErr(err); 
        }
        handleGetData(data.statuses);
    }

function handleGetErr(err){

    enter code here

    error = err;
    }

function handleGetData(data){
    data.map(function(tweet){
      var twit={
        twit:tweet.id,
        created_at:tweet.created_at,
        text:tweet.text,
        retweet_count:tweet.retweet_count,
        favorite_count:tweet.favorite_count
      };
      filtered_tweets.push(twit);
    });
    console.log(filtered_tweets);
    isSuccess=true;
}
getTweets("@sahaswaranamam");
module.exports = getTweets;
```

![attached][2]

Answer (score 12):

The `crypto` module is a built-in Node module; React Native runs JS on JavaScriptCore (when on the device or simulator) and on Chrome itself (when using Chrome debugging), so modules that depend on built-in Node.js modules won't work. See [the JavaScript Runtime section](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html#javascript-runtime) of the React Native docs for more info.

I'm not sure how hard it would be to integrate into a React Native app, but browser module bundlers like Browserify often have browser versions of core Node.js modules, like [this one for `crypto`](https://github.com/crypto-browserify/crypto-browserify).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other similar oauth implementation within JavaScriptCore as a sample..

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [`rn-nodeify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-nodeify) as @emmby suggests, then you can use [`react-native-crypto`](https://github.com/mvayngrib/react-native-crypto). Instructions from the README:

1. Install

   ```
   npm i --save react-native-crypto
   # install peer deps
   npm i --save react-native-randombytes
   react-native link react-native-randombytes
   # install latest rn-nodeify
   npm i --save-dev mvayngrib/rn-nodeify
   # install node core shims and recursively hack package.json files
   # in ./node_modules to add/update the "browser"/"react-native"
   # field with relevant mappings
   ./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --hack --install
   ```
2. `rn-nodeify` will create a `shim.js` in the project root directory

   ```
   // index.ios.js or index.android.js
   // make sure you use `import` and not require!  
   import './shim.js'
   // ...the rest of your code
   ```

But `rn-nodeify` also states:

> If you're looking for a saner approach, check out [ReactNativify](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify). I haven't tested it myself, but I think [philikon](https://github.com/philikon) will be happy to help

---

With ReactNativify you create a [`rn-cli.config.js`](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify/blob/master/rn-cli.config.js) and then in a [`transformer.js`](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify/blob/master/transformer.js) you let Babel transform bundle dependencies using `babel-plugin-rewrite-require`:

```
// The following plugin will rewrite imports. Reimplementations of node
// libraries such as `assert`, `buffer`, etc. will be picked up
// automatically by the React Native packager.  All other built-in node
// libraries get rewritten to their browserify counterpart.

[require('babel-plugin-rewrite-require'), {
  aliases: {
    crypto: 'crypto-browserify',
    // ...
  },
  throwForNonStringLiteral: true,
}]
```

*(**Note**: You can also do this in without these 2 js files directly in `.babelrc`)*

*(**Note2**: Though ReactNativify is the cleaner way, it is still giving me issues wiring up `crypto.getRandomValues` for production-use in RN. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45301900/8295283))*

Comment: Instead of creating your own babel transforms inside a `transformer.js`, inside of `rn-cli.config.js` you can export `extraNodeModules` and override node modules. For more information check out this issue on ReactNativify's repo https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify/issues/4

Comment: This solved it for me: https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify/issues/4#issuecomment-312136794

Comment: @Arnold  After completing all process successfully,  I am getting this error Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Comment: Sorry @Chandni but this is too long ago for me to be able to help, and things may have changed in the meantime. If you get new insights in solving your problems related to the Answer, I'd gladly update the text (or with sufficient reputation you can do so yourself).

Answer (score 3):

React Native packager uses Babel under the hood. This means that you can use [`babel-plugin-rewrite-require` Babel plugin](https://github.com/silklabs/silk/tree/master/babel-plugin-rewrite-require) to rewrite all `require('crypto')` calls to `require('crypto-browserify')`, assuming that the latter is installed in your `node_modules`.

As of January 2016, you can use `.babelrc` file to define optional configuration, so this becomes really easy. First, install the dependencies:

```sh
npm install --save crypto-browserify
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-rewrite-require
```

Then add plugins config to your `.babelrc` file:

```js
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-rewrite-require", {
      "aliases": {
        "crypto": "crypto-browserify"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Restart the packager and that should be it.

This is the same approach that [ReactNativify](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify) uses, except that here we use `.babelrc` instead of defining custom transformer. When `ReactNativify` was written, it was not supported, so they had to go with more complex solution. See [this file from `ReactNativify`](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify/blob/95b6cc8/transformer.js#L16) for almost complete list of node polyfills.

Comment: I understood your answer, but it is not working for some 
reason. "UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module stream from /Users/myproject/node_modules/browserify-sign/browser/index.js:"

Comment: What module you were trying to rewrite? Do you have `stream` package in your `node_modules` directory?

Comment: @skozin thank for the reply! I still cannot make it work for a lib that relies on crypto. The lib is called: `otplib`. Did you find a way how to handle these cases? I managed to hack it with rn-nodeify but it is super agly

Comment: @skozin After completing all process successfully, I am getting this error Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `rn-nodeify` module to get `crypto` on react-native.

Add `rn-nodeify` to your `devDependencies` in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "rn-nodeify": "^6.0.1"
}
```

Add the following to the `scripts` section of the same file:

```
"scripts": {
  …
  "postinstall": "node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install crypto --hack"
}
```

Be aware that rn-nodeify will modify your package.json.

More information available here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-nodeify

Comment: Will this help if one of my react-native dependency uses "crypto"? I tried following the instruction you wrote but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @emmby After completing all process successfully, I am getting this error Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Answer (score 1):

After having tried a bunch of these solutions and never really having been satisfied with any of them (some didn't even work), I managed to stumble upon [`react-native-quick-crypto`](https://github.com/margelo/react-native-quick-crypto), which honestly worked much more effortlessly than trying to lift the existing crypto library to the front-end

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when implementing the Twilio package in my React Native app, and having React Native break over the crypto dependency.

As a work around I ended up creating a separate, stand alone Node/Express app to act as my server and take care of the Twilio logic I had. That way I removed all Twilio logic from my React Native app and moved it to Node. I then just called my Express route in React Native using fetch, which triggered the functionality I wanted to happen with Twilio. If you're unfamiliar with fetch here's a good starting point -
[Making AJAX calls with Fetch in React Native](http://richardkho.com/making-ajax-calls-in-react-native/)

In addition, here's my question on the crypto dependency breaking my app:

[twilio-react-native-unable-to-resolve-module-crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415157/twilio-react-native-unable-to-resolve-module-crypto/36432918#36432918)

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see amazon-cognito-identity-js uses crypto-js 3.3.0 without any additional magic... If that version of the package works then perhaps try that.