# Twilio React Native - Unable to resolve module crypto

Tags: react-native, twilio, node-modules

I'm working on implementing the `twilio` package into my react-native project and when I require it in my file the project wont load and I'm seeing the following error:

`Unable to resolve module crypto from /Users/[myname]/Documents/Projects/React-Native/[app-name]/node_modules/twilio/lib/webhooks.js: Unable to find this module in its module map or any of the node_modules directories under /Users/node_modules/crypto and its parent directories`

I've tried installing the `crypto` package directly and that doesn't seem to work either.

Has anyone experienced this issue, and has a way to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that React Native doesn't accept certain packages based on their dependencies, Twilio being one of these.

While not a direct solution, I created a work around to this issue by creating a separate Express server to make the Twilio call, and calling that route from within my React Native app.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `rn-nodeify` module to get `crypto` on react-native.

Add `rn-nodeify` to your `devDependencies` in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "rn-nodeify": "^6.0.1"
}
```

Add the following to the `scripts` section of the same file:

```
"scripts": {
  …
  "postinstall": "node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install crypto --hack"
}
```

Be aware that rn-nodeify will modify your package.json.

More information available here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-nodeify

Comment: Make sure you read the source of this hack too -> Iirc it makes the rng fairly insecure, so you have to be ok with that.

Comment: For a cleaner alternative to rn-nodeify, namely ReactNativify, see this answer: [Requiring unknown module “crypto” in react-native environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45304528/8295283)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you have a look [there](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968), plenty of solutions are given because none seem to fix for everyone.

I suggest you try the following (taken from the issue from the link) :

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*`
3. `watchman watch-del-all`
4. `npm cache clean && npm install`
5. `npm start from ./node_modules/react-native`

But check out the issue in its integrality, many found other fixes that worked for them.

Answer (score 4):

React Native packager uses Babel under the hood. This means that you can use [`babel-plugin-rewrite-require` Babel plugin](https://github.com/silklabs/silk/tree/master/babel-plugin-rewrite-require) to rewrite all `require('crypto')` calls to `require('crypto-browserify')`, assuming that the latter is installed in your `node_modules`.

As of January 2016, you can use `.babelrc` file to define optional configuration, so this becomes really easy. First, install the dependencies:

```sh
npm install --save crypto-browserify
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-rewrite-require
```

Then add plugins config to your `.babelrc` file:

```js
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-rewrite-require", {
      aliases: {
        crypto: 'crypto-browserify'
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Restart the packager and that should be it.

This is the same approach that [ReactNativify](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify) uses, except that here we use `.babelrc` instead of defining custom transformer. When `ReactNativify` was written, it was not supported, so they had to go with more complex solution. See [this file from `ReactNativify`](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify/blob/95b6cc8/transformer.js#L16) for almost complete list of node polyfills.