# Unable to resolve crypto in asmcrypto.js react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have asmcrypto.js in my react-native app. Whenever I run my app, the build is successful but while running it throws below error:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module crypto from E:\Work\ALL CodeBase\Maptaskr\Maptaskr\node_modules\asmcrypto.js\asmcrypto.all.js: crypto could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  4247 | function getRandomValues(buf) {
  4248 |     if (typeof process !== 'undefined') {
> 4249 |         var nodeCrypto = require('crypto');
       |                                   ^
  4250 |         var bytes = nodeCrypto.randomBytes(buf.length);
  4251 |         buf.set(bytes);
  4252 |         return;
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (E:\Work\ALL CodeBase\Maptaskr\Maptaskr\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:178:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (E:\Work\ALL CodeBase\Maptaskr\Maptaskr\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:264:43)
    at Object.resolve (E:\Work\ALL CodeBase\Maptaskr\Maptaskr\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:170:21)
    at resolveDependencies (E:\Work\ALL CodeBase\Maptaskr\Maptaskr\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:466:33)
    at processModule (E:\Work\ALL CodeBase\Maptaskr\Maptaskr\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:232:31)
    at async addDependency (E:\Work\ALL CodeBase\Maptaskr\Maptaskr\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:361:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 8)
    at async processModule (E:\Work\ALL CodeBase\Maptaskr\Maptaskr\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:279:3)
    at async addDependency (E:\Work\ALL CodeBase\Maptaskr\Maptaskr\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:361:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 48)
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Usage of `asmcrypto.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'
//import {asmcrypto,SHA256} from 'asmcrypto-lite';
import * as asmcrypto from 'asmcrypto.js';
import encoding from 'text-encoding';
import moment from 'moment';

export default class licenseCheck {

    async GetHash(input, salt) {
        var saltArray = new encoding.TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(salt);
        var inputArray = new encoding.TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(input);
        var crypted = asmcrypto.Pbkdf2HmacSha256(inputArray, saltArray, 10000, 16)
        var base64Converted = asmcrypto.bytes_to_base64(crypted);
        //console.log(base64Converted);
        return base64Converted;
    }
}
```

Comment: `crypto` is a built-in Node.js module, which is not available in react-native (as referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836434/requiring-unknown-module-crypto-in-react-native-environment)). What were you trying to achieve by using asmcrypto.js?

Comment: The previous developer used asmcrypto.js to check license. My task is to upgrade all packages. Please check my post. I have updated it.